# La aplicacion se ha detenido

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode

Tengo una aplicacion en Flutter y Dart usando como IDE VSCode, esta aplicacion tiene una funcionalidad de mensajeria y los mensajes se envian bien pero cuando se recibe un mensaje, aparece "La aplicacion se ha detenido",

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Procura añadir código relevante que permita replicar/entender. Logs. Datos de prueba.

Comment: @pikoh alguna solución

Comment: Lamentablemente no soy experto en ninguno de estos campos. De todas maneras, si te recomiendo que añadas mas información a tu pregunta dado que con la que hay es dificil que recibas ayuda. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Conecta tu dispositivo con desarrollador activado, abre Android studio, entra a la pestaña de LogCat, reproduce el error , ahí podras ver el log del error que está ocasionado el cierre de la app.

Comment: @diegoveloper tambien en Visual Studio Code, se puede=